# No sendmail.mc.rpmnew file after upgrade despite having sendmail.cf.rpmnew file

Tags: fedora, upgrade, sendmail

After upgrading to version 21 of Fedora OS, I was issued `sendmail.cf.rpmnew` and `submit.cf.rpmnew` files. Since sendmail uses `.mc` files to generate new configuration, I was expecting to receive `sendmail.mc.rpmnew` instead. Judging from [this thread](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-September/msg00056.html) on Redhat, it seems like a long standing issue.

My question is, what can be done after receiving `.cf.rpmnew` that is different from my existing `.cf` file?

Comment: This looks like a bug as you are supposed to receive `sendmail.mc.rpmnew` files if you have made changes to that.

Comment: New sendmail version *MAY* generate (slightly?) different `sendmail.cf` from the same `sendmail.mc`. Have you ruled out such simple explanation?